# rails 3 - calling model methods from the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a model and in the view I simply want to fetch a random instance of the model in my db and display its name. Do both approaches below work? If so, which one is recommended:

GET /random

1)

---

random.html.erb

```
<%= Foo.random.name %>
```

2)

---

application_controller.rb

```
def random
  @name = Foo.random.name
end
```

random.html.erb

```
<%= @name %>
```

Comment: Probably a personal preference - i prefer to do data access in the controller and prepare all instance vars for the view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend 2): By isolating all of your data access in the controller, rather than spreading it around in your views, it becomes much easier too see what data your views need. That makes it easier to refactor. Minimizing logic & data access in your views is an MVC best practice.